# When is white space not important in Python?

Tags: python, whitespace

When is white space not important in Python?

It seems to be ignored inside a list, for example:

```
for x in range(5):
    list += [x, 1
,2,3,

     4,5]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

White space is only important for indentation of statements. You have a single statement across several lines, and only the indentation of the beginning of the statement on the first line is significant. See *[Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)* for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is really about when Python implicitly joins lines of code.

Python will implicitly join lines that are contained within (parentheses), {braces}, and [brackets], as in your example code. You can also explicitly join lines with a backslash (\) at the end of a line.

More here on [implicit line continuation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining):

Mr. Gamble's answer is correct for indentation.